# masking field (credit number )

Tags: oracle

i have a sequence of *16 digit* credit card numbers, i'm trying to cover the *first 4* and *last 6* numbers of that sequence

```
CASE(target_number WHEN "C~"
    THEN(LEFT(target_number, 4) +
         IF(LEN(TRIM(target_number)) > 4, "*******~", "~") +
         CASE(LEN(TRIM(target_number)) WHEN IS > 15 THEN
              RIGHT(TRIM(target_number), 6) WHEN IS = 15 THEN
              RIGHT(TRIM(target_number), 5) WHEN IS = 14 THEN
              RIGHT(TRIM(target_number), 4) ELSE "~")) ELSE
     target_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

> i have a sequence of **16 digit** credit card numbers, i'm trying to cover the **first 4 and last 6** numbers of that sequence

If that's so, there's simpler way than yours, I'd say. One of these is

```
SQL> with test (ccard) as
  2    (select '0123456789123456' from dual)
  3  select '****' || substr(ccard, 5, 6) || '******' result
  4  from test;

RESULT
------------------------------
****456789******

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view and mask the data there and give access to the view for those you want to see the masked data. You should adjust the regexp_replace to fit your needs.

Here is how I implemented it.

```
CREATE TABLE CARDS_TBL (
  CARD_ID NUMBER
    GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  CARD_STR VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CARD_ID)
);

INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('4024007187788590');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5432223398564536');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5430445512530934');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('4020156755227854');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5431248766892318');


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CARDS AS
  SELECT
    CARD_ID,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(CARD_STR, '(^\d{3})(.*)(\d{4}$)', '\1**********\3') AS CARD_STR
  FROM CARDS_TBL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CARDS_TBL_TRG_INSERT
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON CARDS 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL (CARD_STR) VALUES (:NEW.CARD_STR);
END;
/

INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL (CARD_STR) VALUES ('2222333344445555');

SELECT * FROM CARDS_TBL;

UPDATE CARDS_TBL 
  SET CARD_STR = '2222333344445566'
  WHERE CARD_ID = 6;
/

SELECT * FROM CARDS;

CARD_ID CARD_STR
1   402**********8590
2   543**********4536
3   543**********0934
4   402**********7854
5   543**********2318
6   222**********5566


SELECT * FROM CARDS_TBL;

CARD_ID CARD_STR
1   4024007187788590
2   5432223398564536
3   5430445512530934
4   4020156755227854
5   5431248766892318
6   2222333344445566
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically reproduce asterisks like in the case below as an option :

```
WITH tt AS
(  
  SELECT CASE WHEN level <= 4 OR level > LENGTH(cc_number) - 6 THEN 
                   '*'
              ELSE 
                   SUBSTR(cc_number,level,1)
               END AS chr 
    FROM t
 CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(cc_number)
)
SELECT LISTAGG(chr) AS masked_cc_number
  FROM tt
```

in which **4** and **6** in the conditional might be replaced depending on variable number of asteriks

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PKPN8JWM)</kbd>